# Decrypt encrypted string on a different machine with PHP

Tags: php, string, encryption, openssl

I wrote a simple API with PHP that return an encypted string (using `openssl_encrypt()` function) to the clients/consumers.
When the consumer receives the encrypted string, it can't decrypt it correctly (obviously using the same key) because `openssl_decrypt()` function return false...

What's wrong?

```
/* Encryption on server */
$cipher     = "aes-128-gcm";
$key        = 'my-super-secret-key';
$ivlen      = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
$iv         = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$enc_string = openssl_encrypt($my_string, $cipher, $key, 0, $iv, $tag);

/* Decryption on client */
$cipher    = "aes-128-gcm";
$key       = 'my-super-secret-key';
$ivlen     = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
$iv        = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$my_string = openssl_decrypt($enc_string, $cipher, $key, 0, $iv, $tag);
```

Comment: You need you have the same `$iv` instead of generate a new one.

Comment: @Syscall already tried, same result...

Comment: No, Just run that code as is on one machine. It fails! Then comment out the `$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);` line in the Decrypt phase and it works

Comment: You need the `$tag` too. (https://onecompiler.com/php/3xprr256t)

Comment: Executing the code on the same machine it works!

I followed _Example #1_ on [openssl_encypt documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt) page...

Comment: From this example : _"store $cipher, $iv, and $tag for decryption later"_

Comment: Typically, IV/nonce, ciphertext, and tag are concatenated during encryption (IV|ciphertext|tag) and separated during decryption (based on the known lengths).  IV/nonce and tag are not secret.

Answer (score 1):

```
$tag = NULL;
$start_string = 'The quick brown fox';
/* Encryption on server */
$cipher     = "aes-128-gcm";
$key        = 'my-super-secret-key';
$ivlen      = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
$iv         = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$enc_string = openssl_encrypt($start_string, $cipher, $key, 0, $iv, $tag);
echo $enc_string . PHP_EOL;

/* Decryption on client */
$cipher    = "aes-128-gcm";
$key       = 'my-super-secret-key';
$ivlen     = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
#$iv        = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$my_string = openssl_decrypt($enc_string, $cipher, $key, 0, $iv, $tag);
echo '>'. $my_string .'<';
```

OUTPUT

```
qqajjDNub7pylS68E7QLrHExqA==
>The quick brown fox<
```

You need a valid `$tag` and to use the same `$iv` and `$tag` when encrypting and decrypting.

So you will need to be able to securely transfer those 2 + the key to the remove machine.

Comment: Sending $enc_string, $iv and $tag to the client and using them in `openssl_decrypt()` function call this returns bool(false) but if I use the same code (`openssl_decrypt($enc_string, $cipher, $key, 0, $iv, $tag);`) on the server it works...